# Simple application with Spring+Hibernate using annotation and repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to create an app that use spring annotation to configure beans and also spring jparepository to don't need to create the queries to database. By the moment I have created my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Executor extends AbstractEntity {

    private String company;
    private String responsible;
    private String supervisor;

    public Executor() {        
    }

    public Executor(String company, String responsible, String supervisor) {
        this.company = company;
        this.responsible = responsible;
        this.supervisor = supervisor;
    }
... getters and setters...
```

also I have created my repository:

```
public interface ExecutorRepository extends JpaRepository<Executor, Integer> {

    public List<Executor> findByCompany(String company);

    public List<Executor> findByResponsible(String responsible);

    public List<Executor> findBySupervisor(String supervisor);
}
```

the service:

```
public class ExecutorService {

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public Executor create(Executor calibration) {
        return repository.save(calibration);
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = CalibrationNotFound.class)
    public Executor delete(int id) throws ExecutorNotFound {
        Executor deleted = repository.findOne(id);
        if (deleted == null) {
            throw new ExecutorNotFound();
        }
        repository.delete(deleted);
        return deleted;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Executor> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

}
```

I have used annotation to configure beans:

```
// Informa que é uma classe que define beans.
@Configuration
// Cria o bean para o Environment.
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration/configuration.properties") 
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.metrum.persistence.repository")
@ComponentScan("com.metrum.persistence")
public class ApplicationConfig {


    /**
     * Representa o ambiente da aplicação. Modela profiles e propriedades. As
     * suas propriedades são carregadas através da anotação \@PropertySource.
     */
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;    


    /**
     * Produz um bean para DataSource.
     *
     * O DataSource carrega informações sobre o banco de dados e permite gerar
     * conexões com este.
     *
     * @return DataSource
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Cria e retorna um bean para EntityManagerFactory.
     *
     * Uma EntityManagerFactory cria EntityManagers para o mesmo banco de dados,
     * com as mesmas configurações. Uma EntityManager permite acessar o banco de
     * dados em busca de entities.
     *
     * @return EntityManagerFactoryBean.
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("entitymanager.packages.to.scan"));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna propriedades do ORM Hibernate.
     */
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    /**
     * Bean para criação de uma JpaTransactionManager, 
     * implementação do Spring para o transações JPA.
     *
     * @return JpaTransactionManager
     */
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

And finally the application main:

```
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
        ctx.refresh();

        Application app = new Application();
        app.test();
    }

    public void test() {
        Executor executor = new Executor("Metrum Sistemas de Medição", 
                "Leandro Santos de Lima", "Levy Albuquerque");
        service.create(executor);
    }
```

Well, I thought I was doing it ok but the ExecutorService is not injected so I am receiving NullPointerException.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Spring can't inject anything into an object you create yourself, using new. Replace `new Application()` by `ctx.getBean(Application.class)`.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, but now I receive the error: 
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.metrum.application.Application] is defined

Comment: That's because Application is not annotated with `@Component`, and is not in the package `com.metrum.persistence` which is the package you scan for Spring beans.

Comment: I created a method in config that return a new Application but now it returns that I don't have a qualifying bean to autowire ExecutorService.

Comment: You are trying to get the beans of class Application and ExecutorService from spring context. But where have you initialized these beans? Try adding @Component annotation in both these classes.

Comment: Now I put the application in another package in *com.metrum.persistence* and the main method in another class. I also add the (at)Component in application and (at)Service in ExecutorService. It't works fine! Thanks you both!